# Tensorflow 2 - what is 'index depth' in tensor_scatter_nd_update?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

Please explain what is index depth of [tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update).

```
tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(
    tensor, indices, updates, name=None
)
```

Why indices is 2D for 1D tensor?

> indices has at least two axes, the last axis is the depth of the index vectors.
> For a higher rank input tensor scalar updates can be inserted by using an index_depth that matches tf.rank(tensor):

```
tensor = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]    # tf.rank(tensor) == 1
indices = [[1], [3], [4], [7]]       # num_updates == 4, index_depth == 1   # <--- what is depth and why 2D for 1D tensor?
updates = [9, 10, 11, 12]            # num_updates == 4
print(tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(tensor, indices, updates))
```

[image]

```
tensor = [[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]    # tf.rank(tensor) == 2
indices = [[0, 1], [2, 0]]           # num_updates == 2, index_depth == 2
updates = [5, 10]                    # num_updates == 2
print(tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(tensor, indices, updates))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `indices`, the `index depth` is the size or **length** of the **index vectors**. For example:

```
indicesA = [[1], [3], [4], [7]] # index vector with 1 element: index_depth = 1
indicesB = [[0, 1], [2, 0]]     # index vector with 2 element: index_depth = 2
```

---

The reason for indices is `2D` is to hold two information, one is the **length of the updates (`num_updates`)** and the **length of the index vector**. Two things need to be fulfilled:

- The `index depth` of `indices` must equal the **rank** of the `input` tensor
- The length of `updates` must equal the **length** of the `indices`

So, in the example code

```
# tf.rank(tensor) == 1
tensor = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]    

# num_updates == 4, index_depth == 1 | tf.rank(indices).numpy() == 2 
indices = [[1], [3], [4], [7]]    

# num_updates == 4 | tf.rank(output).numpy() == 1  
updates = [9, 10, 11, 12]        

output = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(tensor, indices, updates)
tf.Tensor([ 0  9  0 10 11  0  0 12], shape=(8,), dtype=int32)
```

Also

```
# tf.rank(tensor) == 2
tensor = [[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]    

 # num_updates == 2, index_depth == 2 | tf.rank(indices).numpy() == 2
indices = [[0, 1], [2, 0]]          

# num_updates == 2 | tf.rank(output).numpy() == 2
updates = [5, 10]       
             
output = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(tensor, indices, updates)
tf.Tensor(
[[ 1  5]
 [ 1  1]
 [10  1]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32)

num_updates, index_depth = tf.convert_to_tensor(indices).shape.as_list()
[num_updates, index_depth]
[2, 2]
```