# InvalidArgumentError: Inner dimensions of output shape must match inner dimensions of updates shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I'm trying to implement an SPL loss in keras. All I need to do is pretty simple, I'll write it in numpy to explain what I need:

```py
def spl_loss(y_true, y_pred, lmda):
    # compute any arbitrary loss function
    L = categorical_cross_entropy(y_true, y_pred)
    # set to zero those values with an error greater than lambda
    L[L>lmda] = 0
    return L
```

I'm trying to implement it [following this tutorial](https://medium.com/@Bloomore/how-to-write-a-custom-loss-function-with-additional-arguments-in-keras-5f193929f7a0) but I'm having troubles with the step needed to set values to zero.

Currently I have the following code:

```py
def spl_loss(lmda, loss_fn):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
         # compute an arbitrary loss function, L
        loss_value = loss_fn(y_true, y_pred) # tensor of shape (64,)
        # get the mask of L greater than lmda
        mask = tf.greater( loss_value, tf.constant( float(lmda) ) )    # tensor of shape (64,)
        # compute indexes for the mask
        indexes = tf.reshape(tf.where(mask), [-1])  # tensor of shape (n,); where n<=64
        # set to zero values on indexes
        spl_loss_value = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(loss_value, indexes, tf.zeros_like(loss_value, dtype=loss_value.dtype) )  # this line gives the error
        
        return spl_loss_value
    return loss
```

According to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update), `tensor_scatter_nd_update` operation should perform the assignment operation, but it fails with the following error:

```
    spl_loss_value = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(loss_value, indexes, tf.zeros_like(loss_value, dtype=loss_value.dtype) )
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper  **
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:5512 tensor_scatter_nd_update
        tensor=tensor, indices=indices, updates=updates, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py:11236 tensor_scatter_update
        _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:6862 raise_from_not_ok_status
        six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
    <string>:3 raise_from
        

    InvalidArgumentError: Inner dimensions of output shape must match inner dimensions of updates shape. Output: [64] updates: [64] [Op:TensorScatterUpdate]
```

I'm running it in colab, [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JT2ub3p1kAQpLp5ESqOhsvna4b8M-MNp?usp=sharing) you can try it.

I tried several re-shapes, because I understand it is a matter of shapes expected vs obtained, but I don't find the way. What's going on here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is that the `indices` in `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update` requires at least **two axes**, or `tf.rank(indices) > = 2` need to be fullfilled. The reason for `indices` in `2D` (in scaler update) is to hold two information, one is the **length of the updates** (num_updates) and the **length of the index vector**. For a detailed overview of this, check the following answer regarding this: [Tensorflow 2 - what is 'index depth' in tensor_scatter_nd_update?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67363360/9215780).

---

Here is the correct implementation of **SPL loss** in [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow).

```
def spl_loss(lmda):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
         # compute an arbitrary loss function, L
        loss_value = keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

        # get the mask of L greater than lmda
        mask = tf.greater( loss_value, tf.constant(float(lmda) ) )    

        # compute indexes for the mask
        indexes = tf.where(mask) # tensor of shape (n,); where n<=64
        updates = tf.reshape(tf.zeros_like(indexes, dtype=tf.float32), [-1])

        # scaler update check
        num_updates, index_depth = indexes.shape.as_list()
        assert updates.shape == [num_updates]
        assert index_depth == tf.rank(loss_value)


        # print()
        # print('A', tf.reshape(tf.where(mask), [-1])[:10].numpy()) 
        # print('B', tf.where(mask).numpy()[:10]) 
        # print('Ranks: ', tf.rank(loss_value).numpy(), 
        #                  tf.rank(indices).numpy(), 
        #                   tf.rank(updates).numpy())
        # print('Shape: ', loss_value.shape, indexes.shape, updates.shape)

        # set to zero values on indexes
        spl_loss_value = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(loss_value, indexes, updates )

        return spl_loss_value
    return loss
```

```
...
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=spl_loss(lmda=2.), run_eagerly=True)
...
```

---

Ref: [tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update)